# Which Gtk container signal detects that a mouse pointer is on top of the widget?

Tags: containers, signals, gtk3, gtkmm3

I have a Grid container with 4 buttons. I need to catch a signal that can recognize that a mouse pointer is hovering on top of a Button. I don't want to click a button yet. I just want to detect pointer presence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The signals you are looking for are [`enter-notify-event`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWidget.html#GtkWidget-enter-notify-event) and [`leave-notify-event`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWidget.html#GtkWidget-leave-notify-event).